# Доступ к многомерному массиву из другого массива

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Допустим у меня есть многомерные массивы A, B и одномерный C:

```
int a[3][3] = 
{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
    {7, 8, 9}
};

int b[3][3] = 
{
    {10, 11, 12},
    {13, 14, 15},
    {16, 17, 18}
};

int *c[] = {a, b};
```

Как получить доступ из массива C к элементу массива B[1][2]. Я знаю, что это можно сделать след. образом :

```
*(c[1]+5);
```

Или так:

```
(c[1])[5];
```

Но как обратиться к элементу массива B[1][2] из массива C, что бы выражение имело вид трехмерного массива? Что-то вроде:

```
c[1][1][2];
```

З.Ы. Насколько я понял, компилятор не знает о многомерных массивах (просто преобразует их в одномерные) и это просто абстракция, созданная для удобства.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Встретив что-то вроде `c[1][1][2];` и зная размерности, компилятор при вычислениях исходит из того, что все элементы лежат одним куском в памяти. Но у вас-то это не так! `a` и `b` не обязательно лежат одним куском.

Так что, по моему мнению, лучшее, что можно сделать - это объявить `c` как массив указателей на массивы

```
typedef int (*matrix)[3][3];
matrix c[] = {&a, &b};
```

ну, или сразу как

```
int (*c[])[3][3] = {&a, &b};
```

и обращаться к его элементам с разыменованием:

```
(*c[0])[1][2] == a[1][2];
```